# Localstack com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, amazon-sqs, localstack, sqslistener

I am creating a spring boot application to log messages on a SQS queue, I am getting a security token error when starting the application. I am using spring boot version 2.7.9, the application is written in kotlin and is running on a windows platform. I have a docker compose file to start Localstack and can create topics, queues and subscriptions. My expectation is that when I send a message to the sqs queue in my bash shell that the application logs the message. I don't know if the docker compose file needs tweaking or if my spring boot configuration is messed up. Please help point out what I am doing wrong or have missed, thank you! I am also trying to setup a test using a test container.

error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleMessageListenerContainer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/config/annotation/SqsConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; Request ID: 4cb154fc-3a61-58ca-aeea-086c2e52e235; Proxy: null)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplicationKt.main(DemoApplication.kt:20) ~[main/:na]
```

AWS cli configure used to create creds

```
aws configure set aws_access_key_id "dummy" --profile test-profile
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key "dummy" --profile test-profile
aws configure set region "us-east-1" --profile test-profile
aws configure set output "table" --profile test-profile
```

AWS topic/queue created with the following commands in my git bash terminal

```
aws sns create-topic --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 --name test-topic --region us-east-1 --profile test-profile --output table | cat
aws sqs create-queue --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 --queue-name test-queue --profile test-profile --region us-east-1 --output table | cat
aws sns subscribe --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000000:test-topic --profile test-profile --protocol sqs --notification-endpoint arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000000:test-queue  --output table | cat
aws sns list-subscriptions --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566
aws sns publish --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000000:test-topic --message "Hello World" --profile test-profile --region us-east-1 --output json | cat

Did this to to check in bash termial I could see the message:
aws sqs receive-message --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 --queue-url http://localhost:4566/000000000000/test-queue --profile test-profile --region us-east-1 --output json | cat
```

docker file:

```
version: '3.0'

services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    environment:
      - SERVICES=sqs,sns
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
      - EDGE_PORT=4566
    ports:
      - '4566-4597:4566-4597'
    volumes:
      - "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

build.gradle

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.9"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management")  version "1.0.15.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.21"
}


group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws:2.2.6.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging:2.2.6.RELEASE")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Spring boot cofiguraion file, I create an AWS test-profile with aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key set to 'dummy'

```
package com.example.demo

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.config.SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.config.annotation.EnableSqs
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct

@Configuration
@EnableSqs
class SqsConfiguration {
    private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SqsConfiguration::class.java)
    @Bean
    fun credentials(): AWSCredentials {
        return BasicAWSCredentials("dummy", "dummy")
    }
    @Bean
    fun queueMessagingTemplate(): QueueMessagingTemplate? {
        return QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSQSAsync())
    }
    fun amazonSQSAsync(): AmazonSQSAsync {
        return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
            .withCredentials(AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials()))
            .build()
    }
    @Bean
    fun simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(): SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory? {
        val msgListenerContainerFactory = SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory()
        msgListenerContainerFactory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync())
        return msgListenerContainerFactory
    }
    @PostConstruct
    fun init() {
        logger.info("SqsConfiguration created")
    }
}
```

The consumer class is:

```
package com.example.demo
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.annotation.SqsListener
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct
@Component
class Consumer {
  private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Consumer::class.java)
  @SqsListener("test-queue")
  fun receiveMessage(message: String) {
    logger.info("Received message: {}", message)
  }
  @PostConstruct
  fun init() {
    logger.info("Consumer created")
  }
}
```

Finally the boot strap class is:

```
package com.example.demo
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
@SpringBootApplication(
    exclude =
    [
        org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextInstanceDataAutoConfiguration::class,
        org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextStackAutoConfiguration::class,
        org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextRegionProviderAutoConfiguration::class
    ]
)
class DemoApplication
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}
```

Comment: The error is saying that the Credentials you provided are not valid. How were they generated? Was it with `BasicAWSCredentials("dummy", "dummy")`?

Comment: I used aws cli configure below.
aws configure set aws_access_key_id "dummy" --profile test-profile
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key "dummy" --profile test-profile
aws-testing>aws configure set region "us-east-1" --profile test-profile
aws configure set output "table" --profile test-profile

Comment: Well, it's complaining about the credentials. I wonder if that's because something is trying to connect to the 'real' AWS?